# Is it possible to run kitchen tests against a server without using any drivers?

Tags: automated-tests, chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen, serverspec

I just want to see if it's possible to run kitchen tests against a server that's always on.

I know that testing cookbooks against VMs that you can create and destroy at will would be ideal, but I would expect there to be some stripped down way of converging and running tests against a box using just WinRM or SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you want to run tests using Serverspec or InSpec. It depends on verifier, `driver` and `provisioner` sections of `.kitchen.yml` are optional. If you skip them `test-kitchen` will use `dummy` driver. So without driver `kitchen list` will look like:

```
$ kitchen list
Instance                          Driver  Provisioner  Verifier    Transport  Last Action
...
ci-server-ubuntu-1604             Dummy   ChefSolo     Serverspec  Ssh        <Not Created>
```

And if verifier supports ssh or winrm you can run `kitchen verify`. Serverspec verifier [can](https://github.com/neillturner/kitchen-verifier-serverspec#remotely-directly-on-the-server-running-serverspec-in-ssh-mode) do it, [Inspec verifier can do it as well](https://github.com/chef/kitchen-inspec#usage).

However, I'm not sure if need the whole test-kitchen if you want to just run tests on the machine. Both [InSpec](https://github.com/chef/inspec#inspec-inspect-your-infrastructure) and [Serverspec](http://serverspec.org/) can be run standalone.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the [proxy driver](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/blob/master/lib/kitchen/driver/proxy.rb):

```
driver:
  name: proxy
  host: testserver.example.com
```

Keep in mind you'll get no isolation between tests, which is a very bad thing.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I haven't seen this driver documented anywhere.

Comment: It's pretty niche since as mentioned its a bad thing to use.

Answer (score 2):

You mention, "without using any drivers?" According to [the Kitchen documentation](https://docs.chef.io/config_yml_kitchen.html):

> This file uses Vagrant as the driver, which requires no additional configuration because it’s the default driver used by Kitchen

There doesn't seem to be a way to avoid using a driver. However, as long as you don't run any create or destroy commands, you likely could constantly reconverge and test.

I think it's important to keep two things in mind, if you proceed:

1. You're using the tools [against the way they're intended](http://kitchen.ci/docs/getting-started/), so future changes are more likely to break your workflow than the typical user's workflow.
2. You're not truly testing how Chef would behave on a fresh build; you're only testing if you can get from an unknown current state to a desired state. You may very well be unable to build a server from scratch if you don't test it every so often.

If you only want to converge and run tests, considering running the existing testing tools in a standalone way.

Comment: This is a great answer as well as Szymon's. I can only mark one as the answer though. But thank you very much. This was helpful.